# Java Nashorn expose java class (not instance) to javascript

Tags: java, nashorn, clearscript

I was using `ClearScript` with `.NET` to expose Classes to Javascript. I used this to expose class (not instance of class to JS) : `engine.AddHostType("Worker", typeof(Worker));` So I could use `var x = new Worker();` In `javascript`;

Now in `Nashorn` with Java this does not work. I am only able to expose instance of class like this : `factory.getBindings().put("Worker", new Worker());`

Is there a way to expose class type to javascript with Nashorn.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your script can directly access any Java class by fully qualified name such as

```
var Vector = Java.type("java.util.Vector");
// or equivalently:
var Vector = java.util.Vector;
// Java.type is better as it throws exception if class is not found
```

If you don't want the script to directly refer to your Java class or perhaps you want to provide a different name, you could do something like this:

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        // eval "java.util.Vector" to get "type" object and then
        // assign that to a global variable.
        e.put("Vec", e.eval("java.util.Vector"));

        // Script can now use "Vec" as though it is a script constructor
        System.out.println(e.eval("v = new Vec(); v.add('hello'); v"));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! @A. Sundararajan

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a java.lang.Class object of the type you want to expose to script, you could do the following:

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        // expose a java.lang.Class object to script
        e.put("Vec", Vector.class);

        // script can use "static" property to get "type" represented
        // by that Class object.
        System.out.println(e.eval("v = new Vec.static(); v.add('hello'); v"));
    }
}
```